# Notification function doesn't work as intended in Godot

Tags: android, godot, gdscript

I have a situation where `_notificaion` doesn't work as intended.

I have three scenes: game scene (named `Puzzle`), main menu scene (`MainMenu`) and `Victory` scene.

When player on android phone presses back key on Puzzle, he/she gets back to MainMenu.

I use this code inside `_notification` and it works fine.

```
if what == MainLoop.NOTIFICATION_WM_GO_BACK_REQUEST:
   get_tree().change_scene("res://scenes/MainMenu.tscn")
```

When puzzle is solved, I add Victory scene to the root node by using `get_tree().root.call_deferred('add_child', victoryScene)` while puzzle screen is the current scene. Then, after victoryScene finishes its `start_animation`, I remove puzzle from root by `queue_free` using a signal called '`finished`' that is emitted when start_animation is completed.

The issue I encounter is that I am using the same code of going back to `MainMenu` inside `_notification` function of `victoryScene`, but it doesn't work.

I tried using the following code inside `_notification` of Puzzle and Victory, and it worked fine while testing scenes individually using play scene button.

```
if get_tree().current_scene.name == "Puzzle":
    get_tree().change_scene("res://scenes/MainMenu.tscn")
```

However, I get an error saying that `get_tree().current_scene` is `null` when I use play project button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have described that you got rid of the current scene:

> When puzzle is solved, I add Victory scene to the root node by using `get_tree().root.call_deferred('add_child', victoryScene)` while **puzzle screen is the current scene**. Then, after victoryScene finishes its `start_animation`, I **remove puzzle from root by `queue_free`** using a signal called '`finished`' that is emitted when start_animation is completed.

*Emphasis mine.*

Since you freed the current scene, `get_tree().current_scene` becomes invalid.

---

You could, for example, tell Godot that the `victoryScene` is the current scene when you call `queue_free` on the puzzle scene:

```
get_tree().current_scene = victoryScene
```

---

About the back button, you could have a field in the `victoryScene` that stores where to go back to. For example:

```
var back_button_scene:String
```

So you can do this:

```
if back_button_scene != "":
    get_tree().change_scene(back_button_scene)
```

And have the puzzle scene set it:

```
victoryScene.back_button_scene = "res://scenes/MainMenu.tscn"
```

And you would do something similar everywhere you need the `victoryScene`.

---

I submit to your consideration to have an autoload (singleton) handle all this logic, in such way that nothing access `get_tree().current_scene` and related methods except said the autoload.

*So, either the other scenes call the autoload, or the autoload handles the notifications directly. So you don't have to replicate this logic for every scene.*

*Since the autoload would be handling changes between scene, it could also implement loading screens and transitions (fades, et.al.).*